# How to Insert an Image above Background

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I can create the rectangle with the gradient background. How to insert a picture above it by giving its path?

```
<Rectangle StrokeThickness="2" Height="77" Canvas.Left="184" Canvas.Top="477" Width="119">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.5" />
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

What I want:

[image: Image above background]

Comment: Change your rectangle to a <Border></Border> and then you can still set the gradient background and then the border can contain your image as content.  Set the horizontal and vertical alignment of the image to Center.

Comment: @Stewbob What should do if I wanna create a ellipse instead of rect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Border` will hold one piece of content, so if that is all you have, the following will work just fine:

```
<Border>
  <Border.Background>
    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5"
                         EndPoint="1,0.5">
      <GradientStop Color="Black"
                    Offset="0" />
      <GradientStop Color="White"
                    Offset="0.5" />
      <GradientStop Color="Black"
                    Offset="1" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
  </Border.Background>
  <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center"
         VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Border>
```

If you need to layer more shapes/paths/images then you can use a `Grid` object which supports multiple children :

```
<Grid>
  <!--Object 1-->
  <Ellipse StrokeThickness="2"
           Height="77"
           Width="119"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
      <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5"
                           EndPoint="1,0.5">
        <GradientStop Color="Black"
                      Offset="0" />
        <GradientStop Color="White"
                      Offset="0.5" />
        <GradientStop Color="Black"
                      Offset="1" />
      </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Ellipse.Fill>
  </Ellipse>
  <!--Object 2-->
  <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center"
         VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

Just remember that WPF starts drawing controls from the beginning of your XAML, so the last control defined in the XAML listing is the one that gets drawn on top.

Answer (score 1):

Since Rectangle does not support direct content, you can place your image where you want in relation to your rectangle and give it a higher Canvas.ZIndex property so it will render on top of your rectangle.

Ex:

```
<Rectangle StrokeThickness="2"
           Height="77"
           Canvas.Left="184"
           Canvas.Top="477"
           Width="119"
           Canvas.ZIndex="1">
  <Rectangle.Fill>
    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5"
                         EndPoint="1,0.5">
      <GradientStop Color="Black"
                    Offset="0" />
      <GradientStop Color="White"
                    Offset="0.5" />
      <GradientStop Color="Black"
                    Offset="1" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
  </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
<Image Height="50"
       Canvas.Left="184"
       Canvas.Top="477"
       Width="50"
       Canvas.ZIndex="2" />
```

**EDIT**

Centering the image in the rectangle always is a different problem. You could have a property in your code behind that represents the calculated center coordinates of your rectangle that changes when you move your rectangle (through events). You could then bind your image location to that property.

Comment: How to make the image's coordinates be the center of the rectangle automatically no matter where I move the rectangle?